# VueJS routing on click to chapter quiz

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am new to vuejs. I need to create a router link quiz with path /chapter/{{id}}/quiz. it will open another component

**Path**

```
    { path: '/chapter/:id(\\d+)/quiz', component: require('./components/Quiz.vue') },
```

**router link**

```
            <a href="#" @click="editModal(chapter)">
                        <i class="fa fa-edit blue"></i>
                    </a>
                    /
                    <router-link :to="/chapter/{{chapter.id}}/quiz">
                        <i class="fa fa-question-circle blue"></i>
                    </router-link>
```

Currently I am getting error
Interpolation inside attributes has been removed. Use v-bind or the colon shorthand instead. For example, instead of `<div id="{{ val }}">`, use `<div :id="val">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `{{  }}` for attribute values. So for your `router-link` component you will have to use javascript string concatenation to add the `chapter.id` or use a computed property to generate the url.

```
<router-link :to="'/chapter/' + chapter.id + '/quiz'">
```

Or if you are using es6 you can use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
<router-link :to="`/chapter/${chapter.id}/quiz`">
```